# how to link abbreviations in enterprise architecture when making use cases

Tags: enterprise-architect

I am a new user to enterprise architect and am developing use case specifications. I have made all of the flows and added the diagrams necessary, but when I generate documents, there is a section called 'About this document', with 4 subsections I would like to add values to when I generate the document. The sections I would like to add values to are 11.1 'document Location', 11.2 'Definitions, acronyms, and abbreviations', 11.3 'Open issues', and 11.4 'Referenced documents'.

Does anyone know where/how I can have this information automatically populated so I do not have to add it in manually every time?

Answer (score 0):

The best approach in these cases is often to use a linked document to store that type of information.

You can then include the linked document into your generated document.